# Conflicting S3 class-names in different R-packages

Tags: r

I see that similar questions have been asked for other languages but I could not find an answer for R.

I am writing an R-package with an S3 class called "Matrix" in it. An object of this class represents a matrix with some application-specific properties and generic methods for it. I need to work with the vector representation of such objects, for which I use the base-function "as.vector". The problem is that a class called "Matrix" is defined in another R-package, and there is a method as.vector.Matrix for that class that seems to be loaded at startup. This results in a wrong method dispatch when I am calling as.vector on objects of my class "Matrix".

```
# using a prefix '#' for the class name in order to avoid a name conflict.
m1 <- structure(matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2), class=c("#Matrix", "matrix"))
as.vector(m1)
[1] -0.2785165 -0.3832539  0.7353889 -0.6382483

# using class "Matrix" generates an error:
m2 <- structure(matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2), class=c("Matrix", "matrix"))
as.vector(m2)
Error: not-yet-implemented method for coerce(<Matrix>, <character>).
->>  Ask the package authors to implement the missing feature.
```

To me there are two problems with this error: 
First, at the time of writing a package, there is no way to know which R-packages will be loaded together with it. This can cause sporadic errors with the package, due to similar name conflicts.
Second, even if there was a way to know of any potential conflicts, changing the class names in my package for the sake of avoiding such conflicts seems quite of an overkill.

Comment: Do you have to use "Matrix" as your class name? To be honest from your description using "Matrix" as the class might be misleading since it seems more MatrixSlices or something would make more sense.

Comment: Find another class name. The Matrix package is important and widely used. And just a small recommendation: "matrix" is an implicit class. Don't create objects with an explicit "matrix" class attribute.

Comment: @Dason I've expected the question, though I believe that it deviates from the actual problem, namely, the conflicting class-names. The answer is yes, because I would like to have a class-name "Matrix" and not something reflecting the stacked structure (although I have considered this option as well).

Comment: @Roland 'Don't create objects with an explicit "matrix" class attribute', actually, I've added the explicit class "matrix", because it gets lost once I specify a class attribute.

Comment: No, it doesn't: `x <- matrix(1); class(x) <- "myMatrix"; is.matrix(x)`

Comment: @Roland: Your example is correct, but calling `inherits(x, "matrix")` returns `TRUE` before `class(x) <- "myMatrix";` and `FALSE` after it.

Comment: You are right. Some "matrix"  methods would need an explicit class attribute then.

Comment: Ok. I mean I disagree because if you tell somebody that something is a Matrix then I don't think anybody will think "obviously that's a 3D array of stacked square matrix-slices". Class names shouldn't be a description of something that they don't adhere to in my opinion. So the general question still stands but I don't think is a good specific example since in my opinion a name change for the class makes sense even without a namespace conflict.

Comment: @Dason: I accept your criticism about the example, so I've edited the question in the hope that this helps focusing on the actual problem.  Regarding your criticism, it is straightforward. I can only say one size doesn't fit all. The fact that some context-specific details oblige an object to be stored as a 3D array do not prevent it from behaving like a matrix. After all, the name of a class should reflect the way how objects of that class interact with the outside world, while hiding the internal implementation.

Comment: "First, there is no way to know which R-packages are loaded together with my package." I believe this is a wrong statement. It's relatively easy to check which namespaces are attached when your package is loaded, but unfortunately not very practical to check for packages loaded after yours. Also, S3 is a *very* rudimentary OOP system. You are not protected against such name clashes and there is no good way to deal with them. Your best bet is giving a class a very specific name (which usually is not difficult): https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/issues/864

Comment: @Roland: I was meaning "First, there is no way to know which R-packages will be loaded together with my package, **at the time of writing the package**. I'd accept the other part of your  comment as an answer.

Comment: In general, naming conflicts is just a risk that happens with R. You create a class `foo`, someone else also creates `foo`, you both accept it and move on. In your specific case, however, `Matrix` is a long-established name and one that's claimed by a package that's part of the base R distribution, so you shouldn't try to reuse it. Consider `special_matrix` or `thriving_for_perfection_matrix` or something else that reflects your specific use case